# Sending multiple status emails automatically with Outlook 2007

Tags: exchange, powershell, microsoft-office

Several years back we created a VB application that would pull user PTO information from a backend system and send out status emails to each of the users on a monthly basis. The number of users is in the hundreds. This worked well using Outlook 97.

Now that we've moved to Office 2007 there are problems. I guess Outlook '07 has some sort of spam filtering and insists that we confirm each of the emails going out.

Is there a way to disable this filter from within VB?

I am also leaning towards reworking the script in powershell if that will give me better access.

Suggestions / Recommendations would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don't know enough to "answer", but it occurs to me that the best approach could be to bypass Outlook.  Aren't there ways to use SMTP directly?

Comment: true. The problem is that I have a list of users Outlook Aliases. I haven't found a way to use SMTP directly without first resolving the Outlook Alias

Comment: Please change flags.  Doesn't look like this has anything to do with exchange or powershell, but needs Outlook and VP as the question appears to be "Is there a way to disable this filter from within VB?"  sorry, I can'tedit yet or I'd help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is lots of information about the [Outlook Model Guard](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=52).  In Outlook 2003 you had very few options.  With Outlook 2007 Microsoft offered alternatives including the option to turn the OMG off.  I write code for both OL2003 and OL2007 and so I can't take advantage of the OL2007 options; Many developers use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/), which is an outstanding library that began as workaroud to the OMG but which has become a much more mature product since and has long offered functionality that was only added to the Outlook object model in OL2007.

Comment: +1 for focusing on the 2007 part. We have a mixed environment here too so I often focus too much on the limitations of 2003.